# Is there a command to print all the terminal processes run by a user?

Tags: command-line, putty

I know that

```
# ps -u someUser
```

will print the terminal processes currently being run by a user.  Is there a way to get all of the past terminal processes that user ever ran when you're logged in as the root user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
cat ~someUser/.bash_history
```

Comment: Close, but I want all the processes they ran like `$ php update_financials.php`, `cat ~someUser/.bash_history` would bring up commands I don't care about like `$ pwd` or `$ ls -l`